# Is it possible to obtain the sum of a variable using the new command "dtable" in stata 18 as it is possible with the "table" command?

Tags: statistics, stata

I have panel data on imports per economic sector, per municipality and per year. I want to create and export a table that gives the total amount of imports per year, i.e. I need to sum imports over all economic sector and over all municipalities and show it by year. With the command "table" it is possible to do it, but not to export it as a nice table. I read that it is possible to export tables in Stata 18 using the new command "dtable". I have been reading the HELP file but I cannot find where to specify the  the sum over the values of variables. I read that by default "dtable" shows means and standard deviations but I cannot find the sum over a variable. Is it possible at all?

I tried the following, (although I do not know if I should be using the "sample" option, but it was the only option where I could see that statistics could be included):

```
dtable ImportPerIndPerMuni, by(year) sample(, statistics(sum))
```

But STATA replied "statistic sum cannot be used as a sample frequency statistic".